# Use Methods in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In ASP.NET MVC4, is there a way to use a static method in a Razor view? My Intellisense is giving me an error when I try:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(
     "Delete",
     "Editor",
     new { viewContext = "report", Ids = new int[Int32(Model.ID)] }
  )">Delete</a>
```

I am able to use the `Url.Action` method with no problems, but when I try to use the `Int32` method, it throws "'int' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'", an error usually associated with, as I said, using a static method.

What's going on?

Comment: There is no such thing as an `Int32` method.

Comment: I'd guess what you meant was `Ids = new int[] { Model.ID }`

Comment: @BrendanGreen, `Model.ID` is an object in my code, not an `int`, which is why I had to convert it in the first place. @AndrewBarber, it looks like the constructor for a struct, so maybe it's a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<a href="@Url.Action(
        "Delete",
        "Editor",
        new { viewContext = "report", Ids = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Model.ID)] }
    )">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why is my code giving me an error?

Comment: Which is giving you an error? My code or your code?

Comment: As *Andrew Barber* said, there is no `Int32()` method. `Int32(Model.ID)` isn't valid; `Int32` is a type. You need to convert to an int or declare something as an int.

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn I used something like it somewhere else in my code. I used something like `String(variableName)` and it worked. I suppose structs don't have constructors?

Comment: `String(variableName)` is not valid in C# either.

Comment: @JacobKrall, According to the metadata when you press `F12` when the cursor is next to or on the `String` struct definition, `String` does have constructors, with specific types of variables, usually `char`. However, when I use one of these methods, `Intellisense` doesn't like it. They must be able to be used somewhere, though, right?

Comment: `String` and `string` are a class, not a struct. You could do `string y = new string(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'});`, for example.

Comment: You're right. I feel like we're going off-topic now, so I'll stop before I make myself look like even more of an idiot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Either

```
<a href="@Url.Action(
 "Delete",
 "Editor",
 new { viewContext = "report", Ids = @Model.ID }
 )">Delete</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="@Url.Action(
 "Delete",
 "Editor",
 new { viewContext = "report", Ids = Convert.ToInt32(Model.ID) }
 )">Delete</a>
```

Or

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Editor", new { viewContext = "report",Ids = Model.ID })
```